# Handlebarsjs: where to download very last version?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I'am looking for the lastest github version were feature functions and fixes are added.  Not the 1.0.0.

There is at least a v.1.0.11 I'am aware about, without knowing where to download it.

For reference:

- [Github.com/handlebars.js project](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) (v1.0.0?)
- [handlebarsjs.com (v1.0.0)](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: Have you tried cloning the repo from github? Then you can pull fixes as they're added.

Comment: I'am not familiar with github (yet), but I need the file today. @_@

Comment: On Git(Hub), the master branch is *usually* the one with the latest changes.  So https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/tree/master should have the "latest" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download any tagged versions from the GitHub page here.
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/tags
This contains zips and tarballs so you don't need to understand or use git

It should also be noted that usually a tagged version is a better idea that bleeding edge master branch. As master is a development branch it could contain bugs. Being a tag though you should be able to assume 'a little' that it is more stable.

Comment: That's what I was looking for: an history page with versions visible. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the following documentation:

> if you prefer having the latest version of handlebars from the 'master' branch, passing builds of the 'master' branch are automatically published to **S3**. You may download the latest passing master build by grabbing a **`handlebars-latest.js`** file from **[the builds page [with a list of ]](http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)**. When the build is published, it is also available as a **`handlebars-gitSHA.js`** file on the builds page if you need a version to refer to others. **`handlebars-runtime.js`** builds are also available.

But I got some difficulties to understand for what **S3, -latest.js, -gitSHA, -runtime** stands for and their differences. Clarification welcome!

Note: My feature is indeed in `handlebars-latest.js`, which I now use.